# Google chrome App

Tags: google-chrome

I am facing a problem that when i place a google ad in my chrome app page,
ad is although displayed, but the values in local storage are not being displayed.
Permission of all url ["http://*/"] in manifest file is already there.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the local storage spec via `localStorage.*` methods? Keep in mind that localStorage is per-domain only, so you can't read localStorage values for domain X from an ad that's served from domain Y.